# if username and password combination are correct by checkin the google datastore

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Edit: Apparently the question wasn't clear so...
How do I find the password for a user in the datastore and check if it is equal to the password given to the method if that makes sense.
end of edit.

I have the following code for checking if the username exists, now I just need to check the password is correct for the given username.

```
public boolean Login(String usernamein, String passwordin) {
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Filter usernamefilter = new FilterPredicate("username", FilterOperator.EQUAL, usernamein);
    Query validuserquery = new Query("Users").setFilter(usernamefilter).setKeysOnly();
        Entity theUser = datastore.prepare(validuserquery).asSingleEntity();
        System.out.println(usernamein);
        System.out.println(validuserquery);
        System.out.println(theUser);
        if(theUser == null) {
            System.out.println("Username not found");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
}
```

I am struggling to work out how I would do this even as pseudo code and I am really new to GAE and datastore but its for my A-Levels

I thought this addition would do it but theUser.getProperty("password") is null i don't really know what the user is in this code but i do know all the users in my data store have a password so none of them should be null

```
    if(theUser == null) {
        System.out.println("Username not found");
        return false;
    }
    System.out.println(theUser.getProperty("password"));
    if(passwordin.equals(theUser.getProperty("password"))){
        return true;
    }
return false;
```

If anything doesnt make sense or if you need more info tell me please as i do really need help :(

Comment: do you have a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setKeysOnly` was my suggestion on a separate Q (and you haven't accepted my A there so it's, ahem, *peculiar* to see you use it here!) where you wanted just to check if the username was present or not.

With that you don't get **any** properties.

Remove it and the properties **will** be there (in your first Q you had a projection, which is fine if your user entity is large and you only need the password property out of many -- but it's an optimization, just like `setKeysOnly` is, and you hopefully know the rule -- **first make it work, then make it fast**!-).